# How to share directive scope with transcluded elements?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am trying to create a directive with transclusion. Issue is the scope of transcluded part is different from that of the directive scope.
I have tried it on plnkr here is the link - http://plnkr.co/edit/vDfXs9zyfAngPqmFCiZR?p=preview
I want the directive to have isolated scope yet be able to switch among the tabs, based on which button is clicked.

```
index.html
<maple-multistep-form steps="steps">
<span>transcluded scope - {{selection}}</span>
<div ng-switch="" on="selection">
  <!-- First Step -->
  <div ng-switch-when="Step 1: Team Info">
    <ng-include src="'step1.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Step -->
  <div ng-switch-when="Step 2: Campaign Info">
    <ng-include src="'step2.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Step -->
  <div ng-switch-when="Step 3: Campaign Media">
    <ng-include src="'step3.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you wanted to achieve, could you elaborate more over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the 'selection' to the directive.

http://plnkr.co/edit/23QO2UGvKwwXK7PRo2bJ?p=preview

```
 <maple-multistep-form steps="steps" selection="selection">
```

and inside

```
 scope: {   //comment scope to make the directive have shared scope, this makes the directive work fine
  steps: '=',
  selection: '=?'
},
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked.
So transcluded scope the scope variable from the directive scope only if they are predefined in the scope, if we define it inside the controller they don't recognize them, right?

Also can you tell me what's the difference between
1. selection: '='
2. selection: '=?'

Comment: Yes, if the scope is isolated you must define it in the scope and pass it through.

A '=' must me provided, otherwise it will throw an error. '=?' variables are optional and can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you :)
have to write 15 characters to Thank you... lol :D